# Android pictures with different sizes and languages

Tags: android, image, resolution, multilingual

i am including pictures with 4 resolutions and 2 languages, so i did the following folders:

```
drawable-en-hdpi  
drawable-en-ldpi  
drawable-en-mdpi  
drawable-en-xhdpi  
drawable-es-hdpi  
drawable-es-ldpi  
drawable-es-mdpi  
drawable-es-xhdpi
```

...and in fact, it works, but the problem comes when I need to include some pictures that have not required language, I mean, pictures with no text. The first way was to include them in the generic drawable folder, but Android do not let me do this and finally I had to duplicate this pictures, I mean, include them inside `drawable-en` and `drawable-es` folders. I have no idea why this happens but seems like if is mandatory add all the images that are used in all languages folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding the images to something like a `drawable-ldpi` folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put non localized images in new folders without the -en and -es suffix.
i.e.:

```
drawable-ldpi  
drawable-mdpi  
drawable-hdpi  
drawable-xhdpi  
drawable-xxhdpi  
drawable-xxxhdpi
```

Comment: It works!! Many thanks, now my app is 7MB lighter :)

Comment: F-A-N-T-A-S-T-I-C! That's a real optimization!!

Comment: @Rotwang i have an question..please help!!!   I want the spainsh drwable for my app, so i have created the resource folder like drawable-hdpi-es , drawable-xhdpi-es, drawable-xxhdpi-es,drawable-xxxhdpi-es      Is it right or m i doing somethong wrong..please help sir

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Yes, that should be correct. If not, try renaming them `drawable-es-XYZdpi` ("XYZ" to be replaced by "h", "xh", "xxh", ...). Don't fear to experiment.

Comment: Thanks bro for help  :)